# Looping through database ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2

I have a snippet of Java code here which is supposed to retrieve results from a database query and the ResultSet is supposed to iterate through the values in order to retrieve certain API data for each entry of the ResultSet.
However, the problem is that I can retrieve API data for only the first entry of my ResultSet.

This code works exactly as expected and returns all my database entries.

```
try {
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from schedule");
    while (rs.next()) {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString("SHOW"), rs.getString("SEASON")});
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    console.append(e.getMessage() + '\n');
}
```

However, this code returns only the first entry.

```
try {
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from schedule");
    while (rs.next()) {
        String show = rs.getString("SHOW");
        String season = rs.getString("SEASON");
        String api_url = "<API_URL>/" + show + "/" + season;

     URL url = new URL(api_url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == 200) {
            conn_stat.setText("Connection Status : OK");
        } else {
            conn_stat.setText("Connection Status : ERR");
        }
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        String s = response.toString();
        JsonArray json = JsonArray.readFrom(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < json.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject show_json = json.get(i).asObject();
            int episode = show_json.get("episode").asInt();
            String date = show_json.get("first_aired_iso").asString();
            String title = show_json.get("title").asString();
            String date_formatted = date.substring(0, date.indexOf("T"));
            SimpleDateFormat original = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            SimpleDateFormat target = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            Date unformatteddate = original.parse(date_formatted);
            String dateStart = target.format(unformatteddate);
            Date curr_date = new Date();
            String dateStop = target.format(curr_date);
            Date d1 = null;
            Date d2 = null;
            d1 = target.parse(dateStart);
            d2 = target.parse(dateStop);
            long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
            long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            if (diffDays < 0) {
               alert_model.addRow(new Object[]{show + " - " + episode, title, dateStart});
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    console.append(e.getMessage() + '\n');
}
```

Comment: If you add logging inside the loop, how many logs will be printed? Only one? Are you referencing `rs` somewhere inside the `/* DOING THINGS WITH RETRIEVED RESULT */`? Or is the code you have provided all there is? If you comment out the code below `String api_url ...` down until the closing bracket of the loop, will all records be returned (use a logger to see how many records will be returned)?

Comment: Once I get the API results for a particular entry, there are no more references to the ResultSet.
After that, only the JSON response from the API is manipulated.

I am checking the records returned using a logger.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej I tried by commenting out the code, it retrieves all the data. But not otherwise.

Comment: Either show use the code, or try uncommenting it line by line to check which line causes the result set to be truncated. Best of all, do both.

Comment: Are you sure there is no exception being thrown? Can't you go through your code as I suggested, comment out different parts of it to see which part of the code is responsible for the result set being truncated? Or just try debugging it and see what exactly happens.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40871/discussion-between-kanishka-ganguly-and-przemyslaw-kruglej)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to split up your logic. This is how you create a list of all shows/seasons from the database.

```
    try {
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from schedule");
        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String show = rs.getString("SHOW");
            String season = rs.getString("SEASON");
            list.add(new String[]{show, season});
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You should then construct ULRs and query the external service using this list, after the resultset (and possibly the connection) is closed.

Comment: I have a similar solution on my job query, but I combined the 3 items of the while loop into one line. Like so:

while (resultSet.next()) {
    jobs.add(new Input(resultSet.getString("quote_id"), "dummyValue", resultSet.getString("job_id")));
         }